# Invite Facebook Friends only if they are not already members of application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, invite

I have a rails app doing facebook invite. I use javascript code for that which is all working fine.

I now want a way for the user to only be able to invite friends who are not already members of the app. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using Facebook Requests and the [request dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) for sending invitations?

Comment: @TomWaddington you do know that it only works for facebook canvas/page apps only

Comment: It works outside the canvas too: http://www.fbrell.com/saved/d72cd188e5853afbf3e7b16363e84b01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using "exclude_ids" that facebook provides to remove some users from list.